# Serial read value does not change

Tags: vb.net, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to read serial data that Arduino is sending but it keeps giving me over and over the first string that it receives even if I change the Arduino output. Why does it give me only first value and not update?

```
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim com4 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing
    com4 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM4")
    Dim incoming As String
    Do
        incoming = com4.ReadLine()
        Console.WriteLine(incoming)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(250)
    Loop
End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Do `exactly` what in your loop? Usually a `Do Loop Statement` will loop until a condition is met. According to your loop there isn't any. I would also check to make sure the serial port `IsAvailable` as well... Also if you check out their site it seem's they have a little information on this as well *http://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available*

Comment: This is just an infinite loop for testing.

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that depending on your arduino sketch, it sends the same data out for some time, filling up the receive buffer, which is what gets read for some time in your Do loop.

Try using events

```
dim withevents com4 as serialport.......

sub datareceivedhandler (sender as object, e as eventargs) handles com4.datareceived
dim incoming as string = com4.readline
console.writeline(incoming)

end sub
```